# Robot_Localization node output is blowing up when measurements are delayed beyond the update rate

Tags: ros2, robot-localization

We are fusing odometry output from a number of sources, occasionally they lose track and get delayed. We have set the system to use differential mode so only the velocities are combined and then the systems state is integrated.

We have found that when measurements are delayed outside of the expected update window that the output of the system explodes. We have enabled sim_time on all nodes when playing back the recorded bag file and it appears that the correct time is being used in rviz.

Is there a bug? When looking at the time-out times, one of my coworkers pointed out that when referencing the log entries for updates that don't blow up, a different time appears to be used.

[image]

Comment: Please paste any code or console output as code formatted text and not as a screenshot. Screenshots are not text searchable, [amongst other things](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)...